# how to disable init_printing in sympy + IPython

Tags: python, ipython, sympy

ok, I know how to use [`init_printing`](http://docs.sympy.org/dev/tutorial/printing.html) to get sympy to automatically render IPython output using MathJax.

```
from sympy import init_printing
init_printing()
```

How do I get it to stop? (Yeah, I could reset my notebook but I'd like to turn it on just for a few cells and turn it off again.)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

found it ([had to UTSL](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/blob/master/sympy/interactive/printing.py#L238)):

```
 sympy.init_printing(pretty_print=False)
```